# Automapper issue where properties in derived types are not assigned

Tags: c#, automapper

I think i'm doing something stupid or this is a bug.

Consider the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AutoMapper;

public class OrderViewModel {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
}

public class OrderSummaryViewModel : OrderViewModel {
    public int NumberOfLines {get;set;}
}

public class MyGenericResponseObject<T> {
    public List<T> Items {get;set;} = new();
}

public class MyResponseObject : MyGenericResponseObject<OrderSummaryViewModel> {
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var e1 = new MyGenericResponseObject<OrderSummaryViewModel>
        {
            Items = new() {
                new() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), NumberOfLines = 420 }
            }
        };

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<OrderSummaryViewModel, OrderViewModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<OrderViewModel, OrderSummaryViewModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<MyGenericResponseObject<OrderSummaryViewModel>, MyResponseObject>();
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var e2 = mapper.Map<MyGenericResponseObject<OrderSummaryViewModel>, MyResponseObject>(e1);

        foreach (var i in e1.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i.Id} - {i.NumberOfLines}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("------------------");

        foreach (var i in e2.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i.Id} - {i.NumberOfLines}");
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/tcoRvK

Now since the type of `e1` is `MyGenericResponseObject<OrderSummaryViewModel>` i'm expecting the two lists to be equal after the mapping. Instead it outputs the following:

```
701cde6c-4751-4419-a2cb-1d347a3eb0e6 - 420
------------------
701cde6c-4751-4419-a2cb-1d347a3eb0e6 - 0
```

For some reason after the mapping the `NumberOfLines` property is its default...
How come? is there something wrong with my configuration perhaps - or is it a limitation of AutoMapper or is it a bug?
Any help would be welcome.

using net6 and latest stable automapper (see the fiddle).

**EDIT:**

Fildor suggested playing with the mapping config:

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    //cfg.CreateMap<OrderSummaryViewModel, OrderViewModel>();
    cfg.CreateMap<OrderViewModel, OrderSummaryViewModel>();
    cfg.CreateMap<MyGenericResponseObject<OrderSummaryViewModel>, MyResponseObject>();
});
```

Returns:

```
1d31bf14-0bf2-4a10-8c4d-92efa9d6e131 - 420
------------------
1d31bf14-0bf2-4a10-8c4d-92efa9d6e131 - 0
```

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<OrderSummaryViewModel, OrderViewModel>();
    //cfg.CreateMap<OrderViewModel, OrderSummaryViewModel>();
    cfg.CreateMap<MyGenericResponseObject<OrderSummaryViewModel>, MyResponseObject>();
});
```

Returns:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'OrderViewModel' cannot be used for parameter of type 'OrderSummaryViewModel' of method 'Void Add(OrderSummaryViewModel)' (Parameter 'arg0')
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, String methodParamName, String argumentParamName, Int32 index)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, Expression arg0)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at AutoMapper.Internal.Mappers.CollectionMapper.<MapExpression>g__MapCollectionCore|2_1(Expression destExpression, <>c__DisplayClass2_0& )
   at AutoMapper.Internal.Mappers.CollectionMapper.MapExpression(IGlobalConfiguration configuration, ProfileMap profileMap, MemberMap memberMap, Expression sourceExpression, Expression destExpression)
   at AutoMapper.Execution.ExpressionBuilder.MapExpression(IGlobalConfiguration configuration, ProfileMap profileMap, TypePair typePair, Expression source, MemberMap memberMap, Expression destination)
   at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.MapMember(MemberMap memberMap, Expression destinationMemberValue, ParameterExpression resolvedValue)
   at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreatePropertyMapFunc(MemberMap memberMap, Expression destination, MemberInfo destinationMember)
   at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateAssignmentFunc(Expression createDestination)
   at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateMapperLambda()
   at AutoMapper.TypeMap.CreateMapperLambda(IGlobalConfiguration configuration)
   at AutoMapper.TypeMap.Seal(IGlobalConfiguration configuration)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.<.ctor>g__Seal|20_0()
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration..ctor(MapperConfigurationExpression configurationExpression)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration..ctor(Action`1 configure)
   at Program.Main()
Command terminated by signal 6
```

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    //cfg.CreateMap<OrderSummaryViewModel, OrderViewModel>();
    //cfg.CreateMap<OrderViewModel, OrderSummaryViewModel>();
    cfg.CreateMap<MyGenericResponseObject<OrderSummaryViewModel>, MyResponseObject>();
});
```

Returns:

```
d9e72e9e-9bc0-41fb-bf4d-33242dca5027 - 420
------------------
d9e72e9e-9bc0-41fb-bf4d-33242dca5027 - 420
```

Comment: Hmmm. *If* it maps from OrderSummeryViewModel to OrderViewModel and back, it would lose the Value and set it to default on the way back... but why would it?

Comment: What happens if you omit the first two configs? OrderSummeryVM => OrderVM and back?

Comment: @Fildor that works. It seems like automapper is trying to do some unnecesary conversions? This seems more like a bug, if you'd agree i'm escalate this to a github issue i think. I can't remove the other mappings in my app because i depend on it...

Comment: Mhh, wow. I just took a shot into the blue. That's weird. Honestly, I'd have to dig deep into AutoMapper docs to see if this is actually feature or a bug and how to handle it. Make sure to post your findings here. I am sure you won't stay the only one having that problem.

Comment: Try `.IncludeBase<>()` ... => https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is happening because `OrderViewModel` doesn't contain `NumberOfLines` property, so that's why your implicit mapping fails (or value is set to default)

```
cfg.CreateMap<OrderSummaryViewModel, OrderViewModel>()
```

If you described that explicitly, you would get compiler error:

```
cfg.CreateMap<OrderSummaryViewModel, OrderViewModel>()
                 .ForPath(
                    dest => dest.Id,
                    opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                 .ForPath(
                    dest => dest.NumberOfLines,
                    opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.NumberOfLines));
```

And when you do mapping from other side (OrderViewModel -> OrderSummaryViewModel), `OrderSummaryViewModel` property `NumberOfLines` is set to a default int value.

So by leaving only following line, everything is correctly mapped as those object properties are present on both ends, so they can be auto-mapped.

```
cfg.CreateMap<MyGenericResponseObject<OrderSummaryViewModel>, MyResponseObject>();
```